# CABasicAnimation is removed in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, sdk, caanimation

I have a UITable view which populates some cells.

Few of the cells have a spinning image. The image is spinned using an animation:

```
[image.layer removeAllAnimations];
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0;
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 * 1.0 * rotationAnimation.duration ];
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF; 
[image.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:nil];
```

For some reason, not all images have the animation. It almost seems like when I start scrolling the table, some of the animations are removed/disabled.

For some reason

Comment: Where do you create the animation? Do you know that UITableView reuses its cells? Are you aware how the cell reuse mechanism works?

Comment: This code is being executed by a method of the cell item. I call it after I reuse (or create) a cell.

Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:
MyCell* cell={dequeue or create new cell};
[cell animate];

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to use a random key:

```
[image.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random()]];
```

This fixed it in my case.